# ¿Como leer un archivo de texto fuera del MainActivity? Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Dentro del Main sin problema, pero fuera cuando creo una nueva clase me da error el **openFileInput**

```
class Leer {


fun leer(nombre:String):String{

    var contenido = ""


    try {

        var file = File("$nombre.txt")

        var fileExists = file.exists()

        if(fileExists){

            try {
                val archivo = InputStreamReader(openFileInput("$nombre.txt"))
                val br = BufferedReader(archivo)
                var linea = br.readLine()
                val todo = StringBuilder()
                while (linea != null) {
                    todo.append(linea + "\n")
                    linea = br.readLine()
                }
                br.close()
                archivo.close()

                contenido = todo.toString()

            } catch (e: IOException) {
            }


        } else { }
    }catch (e: IOException){}
    return contenido
}}
```

Como digo cuando creo una nueva clase  **openFileInput** me aparece en rojo lo demas sin problema. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Como estás llamando a la clase leer dentro del main?

Comment: Así: Leer().leer("nombrearchivo")

Comment: prueba de la siguiente forma: Leer read = new Leer(); read.leer("nombrearchivo");

Comment: Estas realizando las importaciones necesarias?

Comment: si, import java.io.BufferedReader, 
import java.io.IOException, 
import java.io.InputStreamReader. Lo he probado todo y nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no te lo lee porque no tenes contexto. Cuando lo ejecutas desde el activity el openFileInput usara el Activity como contexto, pero desde esta clase no puede. Ademas cuando creas el File no le pasas path por lo que probablemente tambien te genere un problema al no poder tomar el path del contexto, en ese caso tendras que poner el path que corresponda, aca te dejo un ejemplo usando context.getFilesDir()

Aca una opcion de como podrias hacerlo:

```
class Leer {

fun leer(nombre:String, context:Context):String{

    var contenido = ""


    try {

        var file = File(context.getFilesDir()+"/$nombre.txt")

        var fileExists = file.exists()

        if(fileExists){

            try {
                val archivo = InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput("$nombre.txt"))
                val br = BufferedReader(archivo)
                var linea = br.readLine()
                val todo = StringBuilder()
                while (linea != null) {
                    todo.append(linea + "\n")
                    linea = br.readLine()
                }
                br.close()
                archivo.close()

                contenido = todo.toString()

            } catch (e: IOException) {
            }


        } else { }
    }catch (e: IOException){}
    return contenido
}}
```

Revisa bien como tenes los paths en tu app y te va a funcionar

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Un saludo